# error 734 the ppp link control protocal was terminated

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I want to connect my mobile internet to pc using bluetooth device. I installed blue soleil software in my pc.

Steps:

1. I can able to pair my cellphone with pc bluetooth device.
2. I selected my device and select bluetooth dialup networking service.
3. It asks an alert "DUN connection with device?" in my mobile.
4. After Clicked "YES", connect bluetooth DUN connection window opens.
5. In that window there was a fields "User Name", "PassWord" which i leave empty and then in "Dial = *99***1#" and click Dial button.
6. After that it say "Registering your computer on the netwok.." and become fails.
7. The Error is as "error 734 the ppp link control protocal was terminated"

The same procedure should be followed for Nokia 3110c it works fine.But in my samsung mobile c3053 it not connected also i am tryig with samsung corby pro BT3510 mobile .

Is there any settings changes needed for samsung mobiles ?

Answer (score 2):

When I've seen this error in the past, it generally indicates that the username and password for the connection is not correct. (Many GPRS configurations do not require a username and password, but some do.)

Or, the GPRS APN is not configured correctly.

If you are trying to use the device as a general purpose modem, it can be difficult to set the GPRS APN without extra dialer software. The easiest way is to add an "AT+CGDCONT" command to the "extra initialisation commands" that can be configured for the modem in the Windows control panel.

A specific example of what would be configured for this "extra initialisation command" is:

AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"

You would replace internet in this example with the name of the GPRS APN to which you want to connect.

Also, you can refer the following link for checking the connection:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318718

Comment: I would suggest, call up your mobile operators. They have automated/manual settings saved for each handsets which they can tell you.

Comment: Samiksha! You. Are. AWESOME.! If I could add you extra point I'd do it. You just saved me. I think this is the response far more users need on microsoft's forums. Thanks a lot. (I'm using Windows 7 x64)

Answer (score 1):

If you get "*734 the ppp link control protocal was terminated*" with a SAMSUNG mobile phone, the problem is in the phone. On Phone *Settings -> PC Connections* select that your phone will always be in "*PC Studio*" mode. If you select other modes or "Ask each time" you will get 743 when trying to use the phone as a modem.

Answer (score 1):

I almost got mad as a result of this problem few days back. I tried all the solutions suggested in different forums but to no avail.

My issue was not of insufficient airtime as suggested by some folks, nor the ppp link settings but because i had a space before the username input in my username and password field input in my dial up box.

So folks, if you are getting a PPP link termination error, check user name and password fields carefully for a single SPACE in this field will automatically call up this error when you dial. eg

- My user name is: `7032564825@bluebroadband.com`
- Password: `1234`

A space before the first number (that is 7 as in the example above) will trigger this error message. So guys give it a check before you search for other options like airtime and dial up settings.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple. you just need to put extra initialization command.

Please don't read too much tech about ppp and its meaning.

i had same problem in 2006 what you have to do is in modem( the active e.g. bluetooth DUN modem or hardware modem or mobile as a modem) just go to  propertise of : my computer>device manager> modem

then modem propertises> advance> Extra Initialization command

here you just have to put command

e.g i use bsnl net so command will be:

at+cgdcont=1,"ip","bsnlnet"

bsnlnet is APN, if you use airtel, anp is "airtelgprs.com"

Comment: Please don't include links like you did. Your blog is not an answer to this question, so including the link makes it look spammy. I have edited out the link so your post is not deleted as spam.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem, I even searched on line for a solution, but I figured my self based on the instructions that were given from the customer service centre. I have been using a bsnl network, to avoid ppp link control termination problem

1. Activate GPRS by sending START sms to BSNL service initiated number
2. Wait for some time at-least 2 hours to get activated after activation you will receive a activation message.
3. Since bsnl network, we have to create a APN - Access Point Network
   i) create an APN as - bsnlnet
   ii) password as 1111
4. Now change your access point network as bsnlnet switch on your mobile data.
   Enjoy Internet.....